# Графика во View вставленном в XML не отрисовывается

Tags: android, xml, графика, view

Написал простенький View чтобы отделять рекорды на Activity рекордов, но XML не собирается его отражать, хотя вся остальная часть XML отображается исправно и этот View в чистом XML или напрямую тоже прекрасно отображается.

Код класса:

```
package com.killdon.mathgame.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class LineView extends View {

    private int mHeight;
    private int mWidth;

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawLine(0,0,this.mWidth,0,mPaint);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        this.mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        this.mHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    }

}
```

Код XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.killdon.mathgame.activity.ScoreActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|left">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/button_clear_high_score"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear_high_score"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/unable_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/button_inequality"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/button_clear"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/button_clear_inequality"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/table_inequality">


            </TableLayout>

        <com.killdon.mathgame.view.LineView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/unable_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/button_example"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/button_clear"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/button_clear_example"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/table_example">


            </TableLayout>

        <com.killdon.mathgame.view.LineView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/unable_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/button_hard_example"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/button_clear"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/button_clear_hard_example"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/table_hard_example">


            </TableLayout>

        <com.killdon.mathgame.view.LineView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```